# Repeat last "change inside text object" command without the inserted text

Tags: cursor-motions, repeated-commands

Is there some way to repeat something like `cit` and be left in insert mode instead of automatically repeating the previously entered text?

For example, suppose I have the following lines:

```
<th>one</th>
<th>one</th>
<th>one</th>
<th>one</th>
```

I'd like to individually replace the text inside the last three tags so I end up with:

```
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
<th>three</th>
<th>four</th>
```

If I start by going to the second line and type `cittwo<esc>`, it'll replace "one" with "two".  If I then go to the next line and press `.`, it'll repeat the last command and again replace the "one" with "two".  Instead, I was hoping for a way to just delete the contents of the tag and be left in insert mode so I can type whatever I needed.

I know I could make a macro that does this, but for some reason I feel like there is a more basic way of doing it that is currently escaping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a native command to repeat a change *without* including the inserted text as part of the repeat.

You mentioned using a macro, but recording it (using the `q` command) can be tricky, since you want to end it inside insert mode. It turns out you can actually do that using `qacit<C-O>q` to record only `cit` in `@a`, which you can use to repeatedly call it. You can also use an assignment directly to create the macro.

```
:let @a = 'cit'
```

Not sure if the macro really gets you anything, since you're still typing two characters `@a` instead of three `cit`. Granted, after the first usage, you can simply hit the same key twice `@@`, but that's not a huge win...

Perhaps creating a mapping temporarily would be better:

```
:nnoremap , cit
```

Or you can even map `.` so it "feels" like you're repeating a command

Once you're done, remove it with `:nunmap ,` (or `.`, or whatever you decide to use.)

One advantage of using a mapping (or a macro) is that you can incorporate the search for the next location to replace, whether you simply use a `n` command or if you use a text object more aware of HTML tags to find the location. In that case, you'll be gaining more than a couple keystrokes by defining a macro or mapping.